# Cassandra table did not get compacted in 2 years?

Tags: cassandra

I have the following table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE snap_websites.backend (
    key blob,
    column1 blob,
    value blob,
    PRIMARY KEY (key, column1)
) WITH COMPACT STORAGE
    AND CLUSTERING ORDER BY (column1 ASC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.100000001
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = 'backend'
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.DateTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '10', 'min_threshold': '4', 'tombstone_threshold': '0.02'}
    AND compression = {'enabled': 'false'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 3600
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 3600000
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

Looking at the `compaction` setup, it seems that it should get compacted once in a while... However, after about 2 years the table was really slow on a `SELECT` and I could see 12,281 files in the corresponding data folder! I only checked on node, I would imagine that all the nodes had similar piles of files.

Why does that happen? Could it be because I never give Cassandra a break and therefore it never really is given a time to run the compaction? (i.e. I pretty much always have some process running against that table, but I did not expect things to get this bad! Wow!)

The command line worked well:

```
nodetools compact snapwebsites backend
```

and the number of files went all the way down to 9 (after all, I have just 2 lines of data in that table at the moment!)

What I really need to know is: what is preventing Cassandra from running the compaction process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't remember much about DTCS, but if you can, I'd consider using TWCS to replace it. It works well for time series data (TDCS was mentioned to be going away in the near future).

Comment: Oh. I wasn't aware that it had been or was close to be retired. I found some docs on ScyllaDB about it. https://docs.scylladb.com/architecture/compaction/compaction-strategies/#date-tiered-compaction-strategy-dtcs